# Raw iOS Proximity Sensor Values

Tags: ios, iphone, sensors, proximity

I have seen from multiple sources that it is possible to access an iPhone's infrared proximity sensor but I can only find a way to access close to and not close to values (binary (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/proximityState). I was wondering (hoping) if there was someway to access the raw data values e.g. a range.

Any and all feedback greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think this is a binary piece of hardware. On or Off

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'll keep looking because I was hoping to at least be able to access an excess infrared light value as well as normal and a lack of infrared light (I wanted to use it as a sensor to detect extra infrared such as from a television remote or similar device). @AlbertRenshaw

Comment: Neat idea! Yeah I think the way the hardware works is similar to a transistor, but the signal node is from close range IR interference. So the piece only gives an output voltage in one of two states, on or off. But who knows, I tried finding out which specific Proximity Sensor Apple uses so I could look it up in the IEC and check how it works but it seems to be a close guarded secret!

Comment: I'm still hopeful though because some Android devices seem to have a range proximity sensors. "Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY:

values[0]: Proximity sensor distance measured in centimeters
Note: Some proximity sensors only support a binary near or far measurement. In this case, the sensor should report its maximum range value in the far state and a lesser value in the near state." From developer.android.com

 @AlbertRenshaw